# Python versions with liblqr dependency

Tags: python, homebrew, version

I updated python today using HomeBrew, and it turns out that I had several other versions of python installed. I managed to `brew uninstall` several of the versions but it seems like `python3.7` wasn't installed using HomeBrew, and `python3.8` is linked to `liblqr`:

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.18
because it is required by liblqr, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@3.8
```

Currently `python` executes `python3.7`, I don't know what happened to `python2` but for my purposes this has never caused me problems. What I want is just one version of `python3`: that is `python3.11` which I installed today using HomeBrew.

Therefore my questions are: how can I safely uninstall `python3.7`, and can I swap `liblqr`'s dependency to `python3.11`? Should I worry about not finding `python2` or that `python` executes `python3`?

I'm using `MacOS Sonoma 14.0`, and my `.bash_profile` includes:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

export PATH=/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/condabin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```